# PortableApps-style registry call redirection to config file

Tags: c, windows, registry, mingw, mingw-w64

I like the idea of Windows applications that run regardless of which folder they are in and which don't use the registry for settings but use local files instead.

This allows such applications to be stored on any disk or even a USB drive, which can be used on different computers while behaving the same way. That's the basic principle of PortableApps.

An additional bonus is that no administrator rights are needed for the installation, since there is no installer.

However existing applications are often already written to use the registry.

Is there a C library that can be used to build these applications from (C/C++) source code with minimal changes which redirects all registry access (read and write) for at least the application's settings to a file on disk (relative to the running application or library)?

I guess it shouldn't be that hard using `#define` to redefine all Windows API calls to registry functions.

Then it would just be a matter of the right `#include` in the right place and linking to an additional library.